# ffmpeg generate overlay complex filter for audio with background image

Tags: ffmpeg

I am experimenting with ffmpeg and would like to generate overlay complex filter for audio with background image. The code normally works, except for when adding `-filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a` 
it crashes. I found the example code at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform Any help is appreciated.

```
Command '['c:/ffmpeg/bin\\ffmpeg.exe', '-y', '-loop', '1', '-r', '1', '-i', 'temp\\bg.png', '-i', 'test.mp3', '-filter_complex', '[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]', '-map', '[v]', '-map', '0:a', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'ultrafast', '-tune', 'stillimage', '-crf', '15', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-strict', 'experimental', '-c:a', 'aac', '-b:a', '256k', '-shortest', '-threads', '0', 'done/test.mp4']'
```

EDIT 1:

I tested this with the new verson: `ffmpeg -y -i input.mp3 -i background.png -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output.mp4`

It generates an output file, but only the waveform, no background included. My end goal is to generate the waveform over the background.

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using? On what OS are you on? Have you built ffmpeg yourself or did you download a ready-built binary?

Comment: Hello, it's a precompiled windows version, now I am testing the latest. I guess I will need to read the whole documentation then

Comment: Once I ran into problems when using a prepackaged binary, and then I found out that ffmpeg has actually split to two different projects with a slightly different command map. I don't know whether this is Linux specific though (as you could install ffmpeg which in turn was an empty package which installed another package called libav or something similar).

Comment: I will do the testing directly on ffmpeg now and then try to reimplement it back into the script

Comment: There's a FFmpeg fork called Libav, but those tool names are different `avconv` ..etc

Comment: documentation for Libav seems even more sparse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp3 -loop 1 -i background.png -filter_complex "[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x720:mode=line,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay[outv]" -map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, I am testing this now and rendering is in progress, now for over 5 minutes. I hope it did not get stuck, but I am still getting new frames. I would like to make a lighter version if possible.

Comment: Add a `-t 5` to the output options to generate a test render.

Comment: Looks like the background is still black and it gets stuck in some kind of a loop

Comment: Hello, I stuck with the issue with loop option with the latest ffmpeg version. Could you please tell me the version of your ffmpeg?

Comment: Changing the output to `-map "[outv]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -shortest output.mp4` works.